# Unable to set notifications for bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am using the golang storage API to add notifications to my bucket.
https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/storage#BucketHandle.AddNotification

I am getting the following error: Unable to set notifications for bucket: googleapi: Error 403: The service account 'dev-lm@gs-project-accounts.iam.gservice
account.com' does not have permission to publish messages to to the Cloud Pub/Sub topic '//pubsub.googleapis.com/projects/dev-lm/topics/local_sanket_ms-transcript-incoming', or that topic does not exist., forbidden

Clearly, its a permission issue. Although -- I am not sure why the service account looks like that. I am not sure where this account is being construed from or how do I override it with an account I know is valid. Any hints where to look?

Comment: I am having the same issue with a terraform generated bucket and topic. Did you find a solution for that issue?